# How to delete lucene directory along with different segment files

Tags: java, file-io, lucene

Building a lucene index with FSDirectory so that it can used multiple times.. So when a new batch is run it needs to be deleted such that all the different files created by lucene are deleted from hard drive.

**`IndexWriter.deleteAll()`** deletes all the documents but still the some segement files does not get deleted. Please let me know how to delete segment files that is present in the lucene directory.

The different segment files are 
**segments.gen
segments_2**
etc.

Comment: Why not just get a `java.io.File` to the index directory and call `delete()` on it? The call IndexWriter can be configured to create the index directory if not already present.

Comment: This will delete any other files that is not created by lucene. There should be some way to in lucene to delete files created by lucene

Comment: This is a bad idea to put files in the same directory as a Lucene index

Comment: I agree that it is bad. But lucene also needs to have a method to delete all files that it created. So was checking on a way to delete the segments file that got created while creating an index.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene keeps the segment information to be able to keep some assumptions about new segments *never* getting a 'counter' value lower than any previous segment. Deleting it seems rather pointless, if you really want to reuse the location, delete the index as a whole and create a new one on the same location.

Deleting Lucene's files from the outside is a recipe for problems.